# Jquery hover with .each function

Tags: jquery, css

I have a code to apply every li's border-left-color to its background.

But I want to apply background-color when user :hover on li element.

And Is that possible fill background left to right with jquery as in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/75Umu/3/)? It is easy with CSS but I dont know how to do it with jquery.

Here is another [solution](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-button-with-sliding-background-color/) about left to right background with box-shadow property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.side-category ul li').each(function(){
     $(this).css("background", $(this).css("border-left-color"));
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the function with hover in and hover out :

```
$('.side-category ul li').hover(
  function() {
    // on hover
    $(this).css("background", $(this).css("border-left-color"));
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 0 100px 0 0 "+$(this).css("border-left-color"));
  }, function() {
    // on remove hover
    $(this).css("background", "#fff");
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "");
  }
);
```

Comment: Yes, It worked very well :) Thank you for your help!